# learning Ontology web language

Tags: xml, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, owl

I want to write an ontology with .owl format so i need to know all about OWL .
I need a source that explain this language completely with examples.
Please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to read the [OWL2 primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/), but the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/) is also quite useful.  The examples are not the best, but you won't get a better reference than those two documents.  A helpful example might be the [pizza ontology](http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2007/02/12/), which is an ontology that attempts to incorporate all of the various OWL constructs to illustrate their use.

Additionally, if you are not familiar with RDF, [it's primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/) is worth a read.

Finally, the description logic handbook, particularly chapter 2, is also very helpful if you can get your hands on it.  I used to keep a copy on my desk for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language)

Check "SEE ALSO" and "REFERENCE" sections.

After readnig, you can just type "OWL" in the Google's textbox

Enjoy!

Comment: Glad you can use google yourself, but the wikipedia article on OWL is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you, I'm glad too. It really doesn't seem very helpful, but it has references to other more interesting places to visit. And that's the reason of the "you can start..." part of my answer. Don't expect [name family] to become an expert reading that, but his question denotes he didn't search before.